# Performing string concatenation from rows of data in a TSQL view (pivot?)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, concatenation, sql-view

I'd like to create a view in SQL Server that combines several pieces of database metadata.

One piece of metadata I want lives in the `sys.syscomments` table - the relevent columns are as follows:

```
id   colid  text
---- ------ -------------
1001 1       A comment.
1002 1       This is a lo
1002 2       ng comment.
1003 1       This is an e
1003 2       ven longer c
1003 3       omment!
```

As you can see the data in the "text" column is split into multiple rows if it passes the maximum length (8000 bytes/4000 characters in SQL Server, 12 characters in my example). `colid` identifies the order in which to assemble the text back together.

I would like to make query/subquery in my view to reassemble the comments from the sys.syscomments table, so that I have:

```
id   comment (nvarchar(max))
---- ----------------------------------
1001 A comment.
1002 This is a long comment.
1003 This is an even longer comment!
```

Any suggestions or solutions? Speed is not in any way critical, but simplicity and low impact is (I would like to avoid CLR functions and the like - ideally the whole thing would be wrapped up in the view definition). I have looked into some XML based suggestions, but the results have produced text filled with XML escape strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT  id,
        (
        SELECT  text AS [text()]
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.id = md.id
        ORDER BY
                mi.col
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('/', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have already gone down this route. The result is text that is riddled with XMl escape sequences for everything from from logical comparison operators to new lines. This garbled output is not suitable for further operations such as LIKE searches.

Comment: Thank you. This was much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions. The simplest one is to use CTE. This article has good discussion about the topic: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [Concatenate Values From Multiple Rows Into One Column Ordered](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Concatenate_Values_From_Multiple_Rows_Into_One_Column_Ordered)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081(SQL.90).aspx) definition columns which stores the data as a single nvarchar(max)?

Instead of reading several syscomments text (nvarchar(4000)) columns spread over several rows and having to concatenate.

```
SELECT object_id, definition FROM sys.sql_modules
```

Just a thought... you did say simple :-)